# Magento - Run a code at the launch of a module

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Is there a way to run such a code at the launch of a module (once) to add fields in a table in the database

```
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup ('core_setup');
$setup-> addAttribute ('customer', 'flavor', array (
'label' => 'Ice Cream Flavour'
'type' => 'varchar',
'input' => 'text',
'visible' => true,
'required' => true,
'position' => 1,
));
```

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to look into [Magento Setup Resources](http://alanstorm.com/magento_setup_resources). This is exactly what they were created for.